# PostgreSQL Insert from declared table (Stored Procedure or Funtion)

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, error-handling, transactions

Say that you have declared a table in a Stored Procedure or Function

```
DECLARE
lt_error "SCHEMA".err_log;
```

This table will hold all the errors that will come up in the processes that we are executing.
Let's say that now I have this table filled and I want to somehow loop through its records and do something with them.

```
SELECT * FROM "SCHEMA".err_log INTO lt_error.
ROLLBACK; -- Need to have this here.

LOOP through lt_error;
-- Do something with your record
END LOOP;
```

I know we can loop using a cursor but I cannot use the cursor at this time because of the ROLLBACK.
Bottom line is that I need to conserve the information in the log table which has been created during the process and the ROLLBACK will destroy it.
Is it even possible? If so, can someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your idea about declared tables is wrong.

If I have a table foo, then

```
DECLARE foo_var foo;
```

This doesn't declare table variable. This declare composite variable with same structure like table `foo`. But this composite variable can hold only one record (one row). Postgres doesn't support table variables. Instead you can use arrays of composite variables:

```
DECLARE
  foo_var_array foo[];
  foo_var_rec foo;
BEGIN
  foo_var_array := ARRAY(SELECT foo FROM foo);
  FOREACH foo_var_rec IN ARRAY foo_var_array
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'row %', foo_var_rec;
  END LOOP;
END;
```